# How to use floating point support in raspberry pi 2

Tags: opencv, c++

I'm using raspberry pi 2 with raspbian and I'm working on face and eyes detection using opencv and c++. I want to improve the performance and the execution of my program  and I was wondering if I can use the floating point unit FPU?

Any suggestions how to use it will be appreciated.

Comment: The software you are using will be using the ARM floating point unit (unless you are using the original Debian soft float distribution distributed several years ago when the Pi was launched).  Raspbian, NOOBs, Arch, etc all use the FPU.

Comment: @joan thanks , so you are seing that the floating point support is used by default in raspbian and i don't need to activate it ?? and the floating point unit don't need any special configurations ??

Comment: Yes, Raspbian has always used hardware floating point.

Comment: @joan have you any link that explain this  , thanks you

Comment: google hard float raspbian, e.g. http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions#What_is_armhf